# Adding other functions between Jquery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below you will find code for the program. Basically, I have jQuery calls that fades in and out divs. However, before Jquery fades out and fades in another div, I'd like to check form validation and user input.

My question is, how do I properly add other functions in between the Jquery, like I have done so for validateForm(); & validatePostalCode(); ?

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/jquery>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#welcome").fadeIn('fast');

        $('#forward').click(function(e) {
            $('#welcome').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#service').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#previous-service').click(function(e) {
            $('#service').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#welcome').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#next-service').click(function(e) {
            postalCode();
            validatePostalCode(true);
            $('#service').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#match').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#previous-match').click(function(e) {
            $('#match').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#service').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#next-match').click(function(e) {
            $('#match').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#information').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#previous-information').click(function(e) {
            $('#information').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#match').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        $('#next-information').click(function(e) {
            validateForm();
            $('#information').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#confirmation').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
```

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["#information"]["#first_name"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validatePostalCode() {
        var x = document.forms["#serviceForm"]["#postal"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Oops, the postal code must be filled out!");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function postalCode() {
        var text = document.getElementById('postal').value;
    }
</script>
```

---

HTML

```
<form id="informationForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" autofocus required>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is also javascript.

You can add as much javascript as you like between the `<script></script>` tags.

Example:

```
<script>
  function normalJavascript(){
     alert("hello i am js");   
  }

  $(function(){
    alert("I am the jQuery on page ready function");
    normalJavascript();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I will concatenate all the files together after I fully review the function of everything. Makes it easier for me for development! Thank you :)